# Correct password for ssh key rejected when ssh-d into machine

Tags: ssh, git, zsh

When I am logged into my machine directly, I can do all git operations, and when prompted for a password, the password is accepted. When I ssh into the same box and run git operations on the same repos, the password is rejected.

Relevant section of .ssh/config looks like this:

```
# Generic settings
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 600
    ControlPath /tmp/ssh-%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    KeepAlive yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Transaction looks like this when I login when I ssh into my box:

```
{12-12-03 9:41}hbrown-wks2:~/workspace/spt/project@master✗✗✗ hbrown% git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hbrown/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hbrown/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hbrown/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Using bash does not appear to make a difference (i.e. `ssh-agent /bin/bash`).

This is a recent development, but I can't cite the change that caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean passphrase (to be used with public key encyptiuon) or password? You aren't even being asked for a password. If you want password acceptance in addition to passphrase you may need something like:

> PreferredAuthentications publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

in your **ssh_config**.

Also, isn't the IndentityFile supposed to be the private key and not the public key?

Comment: So the problem was that I was specifying the public key as the identity file... I'm not sure why this worked in the general case.